# Unable to generate signed APK : Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmk]

Tags: android, gradle, android-proguard

Error while generating signed APK.

> Exception while processing task java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of
>   [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmk] (with 1 known super classes)
>   and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes)

Although,I have added the below lines in the "proguard-rules.pro" file yet I am getting the same error.

`-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**`

**Edit:**
Now I am able to generate signed APK after adding

```
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

in the proguard-rules.pro .

Please let me know if it is okay to use **dontoptimize**.

Is there any other way?